# Maven artifact Java 9 migration

Tags: maven, nexus, java-9

I have a couple of artifacts in a personal nexus maven repository and they all work great on Java 8 projects. These artifacts all fail to work when used with a Java 9 maven project:

```
Library Maven: io.adenix.spring.util:response-util:2.0.0.M1-SNAPSHOT has broken classes path:   
 /Users/adenix/.m2/repository/io/adenix/spring/util/response-util/2.0.0.M1-SNAPSHOT/response-util-2.0.0.M1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I've burnt the better part of a day trying to find resources online explaining how to migrate my artifacts to work with Java 9 with no success.

I'm looking for either:

- Good resources to help me understand what I need to do
- Pointers baised off my project structure & code below

---

### Project Structure

```
.
├── pom.xml
├── spring-response-util.iml
└── src
    ├── main
    │   └── java
    │       ├── io
    │       │   └── adenix
    │       │       └── spring
    │       │           └── util
    │       │               └── ResponseUtil.java
    │       └── module-info.java
    └── test
        └── java
            └── io
                └── adenix
                    └── spring
                        └── util
                            └── ResponseUtilTests.java
```

### pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>io.adenix.spring.util</groupId>
  <artifactId>response-util</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0.RC1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <organization>
    <!-- OMITTED: PERSONAL INFO -->
  </organization>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>9</source>
          <target>9</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- TODO: MOVE TO RELEASE ONCE ITS OUT -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.0.RC3</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-jcl</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <distributionManagement>
    <!-- OMITTED: PERSONAL REPO -->
  </distributionManagement>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>spring-snapshots</id>
      <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
      <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>spring-milestones</id>
      <name>Spring Milestones</name>
      <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <!-- OMITTED: PERSONAL REPO -->
  </repositories>

</project>
```

### module-info.java

```
module adenix.response {
  requires spring.web;

  exports io.adenix.spring.util;
}
```

### ResponseUtil.java

```
package io.adenix.spring.util;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;

/**
 * This class consists exclusively of static methods that create <tt>{@link ResponseEntity}</tt>
 * objects. It contains polymorphic algorithms that accept parameters to be wrapped by
 * <tt>{@link ResponseEntity}</tt>.
 *
 * <p>The methods of this class all throw a <tt>{@link NullPointerException}</tt>
 * if the parameters provided to them are null.
 *
 * @author Austin Nicholas
 * @see ResponseEntity
 * @see HttpStatus
 * @since 1.8
 */
public class ResponseUtil {

  /**
   * Forms a <tt>{@link ResponseEntity}</tt> containing no content with a {@link HttpStatus} of 204 No Content.
   *
   * @return a new <tt>{@link ResponseEntity}</tt> containing 204 No Content status
   */
  public static ResponseEntity<?> respond() {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
  }

  /**
   * Forms a <tt>{@link ResponseEntity}</tt> containing no content with a custom {@link HttpStatus}.
   *
   * @param status <tt>{@link HttpStatus}</tt> to be returned with the <tt>{@link ResponseEntity}</tt>
   * @return a new <tt>{@link ResponseEntity}</tt> containing the <tt>status</tt>
   */
  public static ResponseEntity<?> respond(HttpStatus status) {
    if(status == null)
      throw new NullPointerException();

    return new ResponseEntity<>(null, status);
  }

  /**
   * Forms a <tt>{@link ResponseEntity}</tt> containing an object with a {@link HttpStatus} of 200 Ok.
   *
   * @param response object to be return in the <tt>{@link ResponseEntity}</tt>
   * @param <T> input type of response to be used as the output type of <tt>{@link ResponseEntity}</tt>
   * @return a new <tt>{@link ResponseEntity}</tt> containing the <tt>response</tt>
   *         object and 200 Ok status
   */
  public static <T> ResponseEntity<T> respond(T response) {
    if(response == null)
      throw new NullPointerException();

    return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
  }

  /**
   * Forms a <tt>{@link ResponseEntity}</tt> containing an object with a custom {@link HttpStatus}.
   *
   * @param response object to be return in the <tt>{@link ResponseEntity}</tt>
   * @param status <tt>{@link HttpStatus}</tt> to be returned with the response
   * @param <T> input type of response to be used as the output type of <tt>{@link ResponseEntity}</tt>
   * @return a new <tt>{@link ResponseEntity}</tt> containing the <tt>response</tt>
   *         object and the <tt>status</tt>
   */
  public static <T> ResponseEntity<T> respond(T response, HttpStatus status) {
    if(response == null || status == null)
      throw new NullPointerException();

    return new ResponseEntity<>(response, status);
  }
}
```

---

### Update 1

Removing `module-info.java` allows it to work under the module name `response.util`. This leads me to believe that something is missing in the `module-info.java`.

I have a temporary fix of removing the `module-info.java` but I'd like to be able to choose the name like spring has done. I'm going to see if their v5 prerelease stuff if public anywhere to see how they did it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you base your project with the structure similar to [`src/com.greetings/com/greetings/Main.java
   ... src/com.greetings/module-info.java`](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/quick-start)

Comment: Also for *broken classes path*, do maker sure that the dependencies are not corrupted. You may want to clean the jars and build again. Do share more of those logs to understand in which phase do you get such error.

Comment: Hey @nullpointer.  I was debating on changing project structure like above to trick the non modularized version into having the name that I want, and that may have to be my answer.

Comment: The modular structure requires a naming convention as linked in the first comment. I am not sure what do you mean by *trick the non modularized version into having the name that I want*

Comment: Actually, thinking on it. Changing the project structure wont help with the non modularized version but changing the name of the outputed jar would. Its kindof hacky but it would temporarily work

Comment: @nullpointer This is a Maven project, so absolutely no reason to change your filestructure. If you want to add a module descriptor, simply add create the `src/main/java/module-info.java`. Maven will construct the proper instructions for the compiler.

Comment: @RobertScholte I completely agree that that should work. Adding module-info I'm able to get everything running and passing my tests locally. As soon as soon as I try to pull it from maven though I get an intellij error that my classpath is broken.

Answer (score 1):

Your module is called *adenix.response* in module-info.java, hence the requires syntax on the dependency consumer side becomes

`requires adenix.response`

Below are the components of module-info.java

```
module module.name // *module name* not package name of current module. This is the name other modules will add under requires
{
    requires other.module.name; // *module name* of another module current module is dependent on
    exports some.package; // *package* which current module is going to export
}
```

The following cases might help explain the components in module-info.java

**Producer** module-info.java

```
module adenix.response { // Module name
    requires spring.web; // Dependency module name

    exports io.adenix.spring.util; // Package name which is exported
}
```

**Consumer** module-info.java

```
module some.module {
    requires adenix.response; // Module name of Producer
}
```

How to change names:

**Producer** module-info.java

```
module my.awesome.module { // Module name
    requires spring.web; // Dependency

    exports io.adenix.spring.util; // Package name which is exported
}
```

**Consumer** module-info.java

```
module some.module {
    requires my.awesome.module; // Module name of Producer
}
```

You can refer to the following resources which might be helpful:

1. Stephen Colebourne's blog: [Java 9 modules - JPMS basics](http://blog.joda.org/2017/04/java-9-modules-jpms-basics.html)
2. [Exploring Java 9](https://youtu.be/8XmYT89fBKg)
3. [Real World Java 9](https://youtu.be/GkP83hvdeMk)

Comment: Thanks for your response! Let me clarify my question a little. I do like the module name of `adenix.response`. The issue I'm having is that I'm unable to require that module once its been added as a maven dependency because of an error that the jar file has a broken class path.

Comment: That I think is something specific to your local maven settings. I built the jar by running maven with JDK 9 and added dependency 
`io.adenix.spring.util:response-util:2.0.0.RC1-SNAPSHOT` and my project compiled and ran fine.